# Unintended dtype conversion leads to uncastable array

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, array-broadcasting

One of my class methods seems to convert data type from float64 to string.

```
    def transfer(self, sample):
        """Takes a list, tupel or arry as input."""
        c = self.bias + np.dot(sample[:-1], self.weights)
        return c
```

If this function gets called manualy with the inputs:

```
sample = learning_data.loc[0, "1":"3"]
1   -0.383362
2   -0.487992
3    0.000000
Name: 0, dtype: float64
x.transfer(sample)
```

I get the correct result. But if the function gets called from:

```
    def learn(self, vector):
    for sample in vector:
        y = self.activator(self.transfer(sample))

        if y != sample[-1]:
            w = self.update_weigts(y, sample)
            b = self.update_bias(y, sample)

        else:
            pass
```

With:

```
vector = learing_data.loc[: ,"1":"3"]
     0       1          2       3
565  1  -0.761398   -1.060793   0
670  1  1.861826    1.822200    0
72   1  1.440886    1.718266    0
898  1  -2.472685   -1.699168   0
1773 1  1.075351    4.293892    1
```

I get the following error:

```
--> y = self.activator(self.transfer(sample))
TypeError: Cannot cast array data from dtype('float64') to dtype('<U32') 
according to the rule 'safe'
```

I first checked checked what '

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Int64Index: 1400 entries, 565 to 1515
Data columns (total 4 columns):
0    1400 non-null int64
1    1400 non-null float64
2    1400 non-null float64
3    1400 non-null int64
dtypes: float64(2), int64(2)
memory usage: 94.7 KB
```

There is no stirng type in there and the function get's called like this:

```
x.learn(learning_data.loc[:, '1':'3'])
```

So there is no proir manipulation of the datatype to the transfere funktion. The Only thing that get's done to the data is the for loop in the learning function.

What am I missing?

Minimum code to reproduce the Error:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import random

class Perzeptron(object):
    def __init__(self, n):
        """n is the number of weights that are needed."""
        self.weights = np.array([random.uniform(-1, 1) for f in range(n)])
        self.bias =  random.uniform(-1, 1)
        self.rate = 1


    def transfer(self, sample):
        c = self.bias + np.dot(sample[:-1], self.weights)
        return c


    def activator(self, c):
        if c > 0:
            return 1
        else:
            return 0


    def learn(self, vector):
        for sample in vector:
            y = self.activator(self.transfer(sample))

            if y != sample[-1]:
                w = 1  # call to jet another function
                b = 2  # call to jet another function

            else:
                pass

v = {'0': {565: 1, 670: 1, 72: 1, 898: 1, 1773: 1},
'1': {565: -0.761397898, 670: 1.8618260619999998, 72: 1.4408856630000002,
 898: -2.472684622, 1773: 1.0753508809999999},
'2': {565: -1.060793281, 670: 1.8221998209999999, 72: 1.7182657719999999,
 898: -1.699168086, 1773: 4.293891907},
'3': {565: 0, 670: 0, 72: 0, 898: 0, 1773: 1}}

learning_data = pd.Dataframe(v)
x = Perzeptron(2)
x.learn(learning_data.loc[:, '1':'3'])
```

---

**EDIT:**

The problem was that `sample` didn't have the shape I expected. Droping the 0 column of the Dataframe and using

```
x.learn(learning_data.values)
```

gives the result I was looking for.

Comment: Quick question for random are you import from random module or np.random?

Comment: I used from random,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well it's not very clear as to whether or not you are sample is supposed to be every row in the table, but right now it's just iterating through the columns instead of any actual number. So I was able to make the code work by doing this. The fix lies inside the for loop inside the `learn()` function:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd


class Perzeptron(object):
    def __init__(self, n):
        """n is the number of weights that are needed."""
        self.weights = np.array([np.random.uniform(-1, 1) for f in range(n)])
        self.bias = np.random.uniform(-1, 1)
        self.rate = 1

    def transfer(self, sample):
        c = self.bias + np.dot(sample[:-1], self.weights)
        return c

    def activator(self, c):
        if c > 0:
            return 1
        else:
            return 0

    def learn(self, vector):
        for _, sample in vector.iterrows():
            y = self.activator(self.transfer(sample))

            if y != sample[-1]:
                w = 1  # call to jet another function
                b = 2  # call to jet another function

            else:
                pass


v = {'0': {565: 1, 670: 1, 72: 1, 898: 1, 1773: 1},
     '1': {565: -0.761397898, 670: 1.8618260619999998, 72: 1.4408856630000002,
           898: -2.472684622, 1773: 1.0753508809999999},
     '2': {565: -1.060793281, 670: 1.8221998209999999, 72: 1.7182657719999999,
           898: -1.699168086, 1773: 4.293891907},
     '3': {565: 0, 670: 0, 72: 0, 898: 0, 1773: 1}}

learning_data = pd.DataFrame(v)
print(learning_data)
x = Perzeptron(2)
x.learn(learning_data.loc[:, '1':'3'])
```

Comment: Thank you for pointing out that I totaly missed what I was actually doing with the for loop. In my mind sample looked like [some number, some other number] because that was what I passed to the function all the time while testing and writing the code.